# Prove/disprove space is complete with metric defined by an integral (triangle inequality still missing in metric part)

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, banach-spaces, cauchy-sequences

I have a two part question: I need to show that $d(f,g)=\int_{-1}^1\! |f(x)-g(x)| \, \mathrm{d}x$ is a metric in $C((-1,1),\mathbb{R)}$ and furthermore prove/disprove that the space $C((-1,1),\mathbb{R)}$ is complete with that very metric.

I don't know how to show that the triangle inequality holds whereas I really can't get anywhere with the Banach space business. I don't even have a guess on whether it is complete with that metric or not so a reference to any specific literature or hints in general are greatly appreciated.

Thank you, ramleren

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The triangle inequality is obvious, if you use the fact that the euclidean distance is a metric together with "monotonicity" of the Riemann-integral.

For the completeness i think this function might work as a counterexample $$f_{n}(x) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       0 & : x \in (-1,-\frac{1}{2})\\
       (x+\frac{1}{2})^{n} & : x \in [-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})\\ 1 & : x \in [\frac{1}{2},1)
     \end{array}
   \right.$$ I let you sort out the details.

Comment: Thank you. The part about the triangle inequality I understand but I am not sure that I can follow on the completeness part.

Comment: The function you are proposing is the same for any n,m>N on the first and third interval at which it is defined so that part satisfies the cauchy criterion, yes? But isn't that also the case with the second interval? One can always choose n,m big enough so that the two terms of the sequence will be arbitrarily close?

Comment: To show that $f_{n}$ is a cauchy sequence the only interval to consider is indeed the middle one in our case. You can just calculate it explicitely since it is only a difference between two powers of x and let m,n tend to infinity. Next is to show that this sequence cannot converge to a continuous function on (-1,1)